# How to handle java dynamic objects in QTP?

Tags: automated-testing, java, qtp, qtp-11.0

How can I handle Java dynamic objects in QTP 11.0?

There is a smoke test scenario where simple search is performed and the first occurance in JavaTable is selected (by double click) then sub-window opens (JavaWindow). I can add this subwindow to the Object Repository and make any action with it.

The test runs fine until database changes. Then subwindow is opened by clicking on another item (first item has changed) also sub-window name has changed correspondingly to selected item's name. And QTP throws `Object not found in object repository` error.

But the sub-window structure is still the same and basic actions I want to check is the same. How can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove parameters that are changed in `Test Object Details` and add description properties that will describe your object well enough to distinguish from others. (This is done after object is added to Object Repository by means of Object Spy)

In my case I removed `title` property (it was changing) and added:

- toolkit class
- to_description
- path
- class_path

[image: Add-remove descripption properties]